# First time making beer

Tags: beer, fermentation

I'm living somewhere possessing and trading alcoholic beverages is illegal and that is why I'm making my own. I can find some russian beers here which according to what is sated on the can, they contain 0.5% alcohol and they do not have any preservatives in them. Since also special kinds of yeasts are not available here, I'm using normal baking yeast. So, what is did was purchasing some of those russian beers and pouring them into a container and I mixed some sugar with warm (20 c) water and added the yeast to it. I left the sugar water for a while and it started foaming then I added that to the container (yesterday) and put it aside. Now the beer in the container is like boiling and it is bubbling too fast. It's been fermenting for exactly 24 hours and I wanted to know how long I have to leave it like that, and how much alcohol can I expect to be in there. Just tastes a little and it really tasted cool, it not bready and it already tastes real beer but can taste alcohol very much.

Comment: Firstly, let it ferment until it stops bubbling.  Secondly, if someone were to try to take a stab at the ABV, you'd have to say how much sugar you added and also how much beer you added the 20 cups of water to.  You're really going to some crazy lengths to make whatever you end up making, I'll say that much.

Comment: On a similar note, a friend of mine claimed to have been able to ferment Malta (a product in the US that's essentially unfermented beer) by adding brewers yeast to it. So what you are doing is in the realm of possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a typical 5% ABV beer, brewed between 16 and 20°C, allow 10-14 days for fermentation to stop, and few more days for the yeast to clear. But using bread yeast might get you a different result.

Starting with about 10% sugar you would expect to get a 4-5% beer, but your yeast might have other ideas and quit before it gets that far. After the bubbling stops, if it's too sweet for your taste, you can try adding more yeast. Just don't shake up the beer, it will mess up the flavor.

Side question - is the russian beer there for the hops or does it have malt too?

Best of luck, I hope it works out for you.